# My croton is not growing

Tags: plant-care

I have bought this like 3 to 4 month ago it has some leaf fall but no more recently .the problem is it did not grow one leaf since I've got it and also it have spider mites.[image]

Comment: What evidence have you seen that you have spider mites? Have you treated the plant for spider mite?

Comment: Thank u for answering I saw silky webbing on the stem I sprayed and clean it . It was gone for a while but now it's back